# Why does Mysql rename my foreign key?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

Why does Mysql/InnoDB seem to rename some of the foreign keys I create?

e.g.

```
mysql> alter table JOB_LISTENER add foreign key FK_JOBS (job_id) REFERENCES job(id);
mysql>
mysql> show create table JOB_LISTENER;
snip> ....
mysql> CONSTRAINT `JOB_LISTENER_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (job_id) REFERENCES job (id)
snip> ....
```

it renames the foreign key i created named FK_JOBS to JOB_LISTENER_ibfk_4 - any ideas why it does that?

Many thanks,

Sean

Comment: You did not provide a name for the foreign key constraint so MYSQL had to create one. The `FK_JOBS` you have is the index_name to be used by the FK constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `CONSTRAINT` keyword to name a constraint:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE JOB_LISTENER ADD CONSTRAINT FK_JOBS FOREIGN KEY (job_id) 
  REFERENCES job(id);
```

This automatically names the index to the same name, if it needs to create an index.

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE JOB_LISTENER\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: JOB_LISTENER
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `JOB_LISTENER` (
  `job_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `FK_JOBS` (`job_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_JOBS` FOREIGN KEY (`job_id`) REFERENCES `job` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html says:

> If the CONSTRAINT symbol clause is given, the symbol value, if used, must be unique in the database. A duplicate symbol will result in an error similar to: ERROR 1022 (2300): Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql- 464_1'. If the clause is not given, or a symbol is not included following the CONSTRAINT keyword, a name for the constraint is created automatically.

Sometimes you have to read between the lines. In the above paragraph, I infer from the last sentence that you *must* use the CONSTRAINT keyword to give a name for the constraint, because if you don't, then the constraint name is created automatically.

Tip: Be aware that constraint names must be unique within the database, not only within the table. Go figure, this is part of the SQL standard. So you may not expect this, so be careful not to use duplicate constraint names.

Whereas in some implementations you can use the same index name in multiple tables in the same database (the SQL standard does not cover index implementation, as a_horse_with_no_name reminds me).

Comment: "*this is part of the SQL standard*" - Indexes are not part of the SQL standard at all. Only constraints and the rules for naming objects in the database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes, you are correct, I know that, but I didn't phrase it precisely. I have edited the above.

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much Bill. I had thought that I had named the Foreign Key with my code. I had thought the CONSTRAINT keyword was option. Better get back to my manual. Thanks again  ^_^